# predict_proba method available in OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning

I am using `sklearn`'s [OneVsOneClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html) in an pipeline like so:

```
smt = SMOTE(random_state=42)
base_model = LogisticRegression()
pipeline = Pipeline([('sampler', smt), ('model', base_model)])

classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(estimator=pipeline)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
# prediction
yhat = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

But then I cannot do:

```
yhat_prob = predict_proba(X_test)

AttributeError: 'OneVsOneClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

`scikit-learn`s [OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) does provide [predict_proba](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba) method. I am suprised [OneVsOneClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier.html) doesn't have this method.

How do I then get class probability estimates from my pipeline above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how to use OvO to get probabilities, so it's not implemented. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6164

There is the `decision_function` method for a more nuanced version of `predict`.